# r ggplot different size depending on shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, shapes

I have the following R code:

```
x <- rep(c(1:5), 5)
y <- rep(1:5, each=5)
z <- rep(seq(0, 1000, 250), each=5)
w1 <- c(15:18,25)
w2 <- c("\u25A0", "\u25CF", "\u25B2", "\u25C6", "\u25BC")
t <- c(rep(c("a", "s", "d", "f", "g"), 5))
col <- c("red", "blue", "green", "black", "yellow")

data <- cbind.data.frame(x,y,z,t)

ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, shape=t, size=z, color=as.factor(z))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=w1) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits=c(0, 1000), 
                        breaks=c(0,250,500,1000)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=col, guide="none")

ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, shape=t, size=z, color=as.factor(z))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=w2) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits=c(0, 1000), 
                      breaks=c(0,250,500,1000)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=col, guide="none")
```

My question: in the first pciture, the sizes of the shapes in the plot and the sizes on the legend are comparable. In the second plot, the sizes of the shapes in the plot do not correspond to the sizes on the legend; they are too small. Why is this the case? What I finally would like, is to have the first plot but with filled out down triangles or the second plot with a correct size on the legend. How can I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the size of the shapes in the shape legend by using `override.aes` in the scale's guide. Here, we'll change it to `size = 6`:

```r
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y, shape = t, size = z, color = as.factor(z))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = w2, 
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 6))) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = c(0, 1000), 
                        breaks = c(0, 250, 500, 1000),
                        guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = "●"))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col, guide = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer! But how can I assure, that the circle which equals 1000 in the legend has the same size as the circle in the plot with value 1000? In the  above picture the corresponding circle in the legend is much bigger than in the plot (x=3,y=5).

Comment: @MPB_2022 that's because the circle you are using in your plot is a different glyph from the standard filled circle in ggplot. Again, you would need to override the default glyph in the size scale to match the actual glyph you are using. See my update.

Comment: Perfect! Thx a lot!